# How to combine date and time into one variable using Stata

Tags: stata

My database is a panel dataset which contains variable `name`, `date`, `time`.

The format of `date` looks like this 02jan2002. `time` is a artificial time stamp whose value is between 20 and 32. I want to combine `date` and `time` and create a new variable, so I can `tsset` this variable.

Can anyone tell me how to combine these two variables?

Comment: You need to tell us what is meant by 20 to 32 in terms of hours and minutes; it's really not obvious.

Comment: I divided the day into 48 half hour interval. 1 means 0:00 -0:30.  20 means 9:30-10:00. Similarly, 32 represent the interval between 15:30-16:00.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `tsset` or to `xtset` the data all that is needed are integer dates or datetimes. But here it seems that you have no observations over most of the day, i.e. only 6 hr 30 min of observations each day and 17 hr 30 min of gaps.

You would need a convention to use one time and one time only for each 30 min period. Choosing the beginning of each period as one convention, you could generate date-times using

```
gen double datetime = cofd(date) + (time - 1) * 30 * 60000
format %tc
```

given that `date` appears to be a Stata daily date variable and that `time`  encodes 30 minute intervals and there are 60000 ms in each minute.

In declaring identifier and time, you would need to specify `delta(1800000)`,

As said, the gaps are made obvious by this declaration. Whether you need a fiction that the clock stops when observations are not being made is an open question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
clear
set obs 3
gen id = _n
expand 2
bys id: gen date = 20200 + _n
format date %td
expand 13
bys id date: gen time = _n+19
sort id date time

gen double ts = dhms(date,round((time)*30/60,1)-1,mod(time*30+30,60),0.000)
format ts %tcDDmonCCYY_HH:MM
tsset id ts, delta(30 minutes)
```

The idea behind this is the same as Nick's solution, though his is more efficient. I convert the time interval variable into hours and into minutes. I feed these to the `dhms()` function, which expects the first argument to be a `%td` date variable, the second to be hours, the third to be minutes, and the last to be seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, my time only contains value between 20-32. so  ts = dhms(date,sum(mod(time,2))-1,mod(time*30+30,60),0.000) does not really work. Could you teach me how to adjust this code please.

Comment: The new solution handles it much better.

Comment: Some overlap and some offlap between answers, which is fine for a problem with different solutions of varying merit. Could you spell out in words what your solution does?